# SQL Query - I am stumped... excluding records

Tags: sql

Please see the attached mage, which are records for an employee for a 7 day period.  What I am trying to do is exclude all employee records (7) if the sum of all 7 records for each column (ST, OT, DT, PayPerdiem, PayTruck, PayTravel) are equal to zero.

Basically, I want all 7 records from the employee if the any of the totals are greater than 0, and none of the records of all the employees totals are equal to 0.

So Employee ATES should not return any records, but employee BEADLING should return 7 records.

Does this make sense?  Can anyone help?  This is to feed a pivot table and after to days of attempts, I simply can't figure it out. Please help.

[image]

Comment: There's no attached image? Code posted into your question would be better though..

Comment: Added.  Sorry - first post

Comment: To improve the quality of your question, please replicate the field names and sample data as a text table in the Question.  Please also do another text table showing how you wish for the results to appear.  Please also show us the code that you have tried (if any) and the full text of any error messages that it produces.

Comment: what is your RDBMS? MySQL Postgres?

Comment: This is a really simple site for transforming data into text tables, you can just copy and paste from SSMS or excel, etc: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Does it need to print all 7 rows? Or can it just output one row with their name if the criteria is met. Quick answer if the latter: `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE criteria GROUP BY Employee HAVING (SUM(ST) > 0 AND SUM(OT) > 0 AND SUM(DT) > 0)`

Comment: @Jackson `Basically, I want all 7 records from the employee if the any of the totals are greater than 0,`

Comment: Can any of the six totals fields hold a negative value?

Comment: I tested Juan's code and it produced exactly what I was looking for.  I thank all of those who answered (especially Juan) because I truly could not figure out a simple way of excluding the records.

Answer (score 1):

You could return all records for an employee where at least one row for that employee has a value greater than `0` using `exists()` like so:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t i
  where i.Employee = t.Employee
    and (
         st > 0
      or ot > 0
      or dt > 0
      or payperdiem > 0
      or paytruck   > 0
      or paytravel  > 0
      )
   )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VOOH64182

For this sample data:

```
create table t (Employee int, calendardate date, st int, ot int, dt int, payperdiem int, paytruck int, paytravel int)
insert into t values
 (1,'20170401',0,0,0,0,0,0)
,(1,'20170402',0,0,0,0,0,0)
,(1,'20170403',0,0,0,0,0,0)
,(1,'20170404',2,0,0,0,0,0) /* this one has a value */
,(2,'20170401',0,0,0,0,0,0)
,(2,'20170402',0,0,0,0,0,0)
,(2,'20170403',0,0,0,0,0,0)
,(2,'20170404',0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

returns:

```
+----------+--------------+----+----+----+------------+----------+-----------+
| Employee | calendardate | st | ot | dt | payperdiem | paytruck | paytravel |
+----------+--------------+----+----+----+------------+----------+-----------+
|        1 | 2017-04-01   |  0 |  0 |  0 |          0 |        0 |         0 |
|        1 | 2017-04-02   |  0 |  0 |  0 |          0 |        0 |         0 |
|        1 | 2017-04-03   |  0 |  0 |  0 |          0 |        0 |         0 |
|        1 | 2017-04-04   |  2 |  0 |  0 |          0 |        0 |         0 |
+----------+--------------+----+----+----+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I think this will only print rows where there are non-zero values, not all 7 rows if one of them has a non-zero value in one of the three columns. True?

Comment: @Jackson Not true.

Comment: @Jackson I've added a simple demo to illustrate.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I tried out a similar query on our own DB. This works great!

Comment: @J. Stanich try this one out, seems to be the most efficient. I'll be making a mental note of it too

Answer (score 1):

If you can have negative values you may need compare the `SUM` instead.

```
 SELECT t1.*
 FROM t as t1
 JOIN (SELECT Employee
       FROM t 
       GROUP BY Employee
       HAVING SUM(st) > 0
           OR SUM(ot) > 0
           OR SUM(dt) > 0
           OR SUM(payperdiem) > 0
           OR SUM(paytruck)   > 0
           OR SUM(paytravel)  > 0
      ) as t2
   ON t1.Employee = t2.Employee
```

Comment: Thank you Juan.  Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT CalendarDate,
       tblTable.Employee,
       PayCodeName,
       ST,
       OT,
       DT,
       PayPerdiem,
       PayTruck,
       PayTravel
FROM tblTable
JOIN ( SELECT Employee
       FROM tblTable
       GROUP BY Employee
       HAVING SUM( ST +
                   OT +
                   DT +
                   PayPerdiem +
                   PayTruck +
                   PayTravel ) > 0
     ) EmployeeFinder ON tblTable.Employee = EmployeeFinder.Employee
ORDER BY tblTable.Employee,
         CalenadrDate;
```

This statement starts by grouping each record from `tblTable` by `Employee` and then refines that list to only those groups that have a grand total of all totals fields that is greater than `0`.

An `INNER JOIN` is then performed on the resulting dataset with `tblTable`, which has the effect of eliminating any record for an `Employee` that does not appear in our subquery's results.

The fields of the surviving records of `tblTable` are then selected and the record sorted.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.